# zope 2.11 upload page template via build script

Tags: zope, zpt, zenoss

I want to maintain a zope page template as a file in svn and upload it to zope whenever it changes. I can of course upload it through the zope management interface, but I need to automate that procedure. Is there a way? My system is zenoss-2.5.2 on zope 2.11.

Comment: Why can't you maintain all your source code on the file system using a proper policy package?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner at Zope/Zenoss. What is a "policy package". Can you please point me to some documentation that might be relevant to zope 2.11?

Comment: Google "svn post-commit hook". This means, after each commit to SVN a script is executed. This script could upload your code to Zope.